# How to serialize a complex interface with unexported fields?

Tags: serialization, go, gob

I need to serialize some complex interface (template.Template). It has many unexported fields, and gob don't want to work with them. Any suggestions?

P.S. Actualy, I trying to put a parsed template to memcache on App Engine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that there's usually a reason for unexported fields--[`template.Template`](http://golang.org/src/pkg/template/template.go?s=5467:5788#L166), for instance, contains information which changes during parsing--so I'd advise against serializing them yourself with `reflect`. However, the `GobEncoder` and `GobDecoder` interfaces were recently added to `gob`; if you need to serialize a complex struct with unexported fields, encourage the author of the package to implement these interfaces. Even better, implement them yourself (shouldn't be hard for `template.Template`) and [contribute](http://golang.org/doc/contribute.html) your patch.

Answer (score 1):

If the type is from another package (such as template) this can't be done with any of the current serialization libs for Go (`gob`, `json`, bson, etc.). Nor *should* it be done, because the fields are unexported.

However, if you really need to, you can write your own serializer using package [`reflect`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect), specifically `Value.Field()` and friends to get the unexported fields. Then you just need to store them in a way that you can decode later.